# Is a Google Analytics view updated when a filter is removed?

Tags: google-analytics

Several months ago a filter was erroneously added to a view for an entire domain. E.g. The view for `example.com` was accidentally limited to `raresubdomain**\\.example.com`, so almost no data shows up since that day.

I've just removed this filter, and data for the full domain is now showing up in the Real-Time section, but will the view of the past days be updated in response to my filter removal?

If not, is there anyway to request an update, or access all that data my site was sending them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't retrieve the data that was filtered out. The data sent by the tracking code for a property is processed by all the views according to the filters and only the filtered data will be stored.

See [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en&ref_topic=1102143&rd=1) page from Google Analytics Help Center

> When you add a property to an account, Analytics creates the first
>   view for that property. That first view has no filters, and so
>   includes all the data for that property. To ensure that you always
>   have access to all of the data for a property, do not delete that
>   first unfiltered view.
>
> When you create a view, you can then report on that particular data
>   from the creation date of the view forward. For example, if you create
>   a view on June 1, then you can report on data from June 1 forward, but
>   not on any data collected prior to June 1.

[Here](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/beyond-standard-reporting/) is another reference :

> remember that anything you filter out will be unavailable to you in
>   this profile. Therefore, if you are going to use very specific filters
>   (like a filter to show only traffic from the United States), you will
>   want to create an additional profile that is unfiltered so you have
>   all of your data somewhere if you need it.